# jquery append img src why doesnt variable work for address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery to append a variable from nodeJS/MongoDB that has a profile picture address for example:
profile_pic-1512068176863.gif
Why is it when I copy and paste that literally into the string it displays the image, but when I use the variable comPic it doesn't? It's the same value. How do I make it work? Don't know what else to try.

error:localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/ 404 (Not Found)

```
var comPic = commentList[cl].by.profile_pic;
           $("#messages").append('<div class= "comment__item">' + '<div class="infos">' + '<img src="../uploads/"' + comPic + ">" + "</div>" + '<div class="content">' + '<h3 class="comment__authorname>"' + commentList[cl].by.name + "</h3>" + "<br>" + '<b class="comment__time">' + "</b>" + "<br>" + "<p>"+ commentList[cl].body + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>");
```

Comment: Please don't make us horizontal scroll through a long code snipplet.  Also can you provide the json structore of the commentList?

Comment: Check the quoting, the value of `src` ends before you intended.

Comment: Don't mix the quotes... The constructed `<img>` is this: `<img src="../uploads/"profile_pic-1512068176863.gif>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable should be with in the quotes

```
src="../uploads/' + comPic + '">'
```

like this

```
  $("#messages").append('<div class= "comment__item">' + '<div class="infos">' + '<img src="../uploads/' + comPic + '">' + "</div>" + '<div class="content">' + '<h3 class="comment__authorname>"' + commentList[cl].by.name + "</h3>" + "<br>" + '<b class="comment__time">' + "</b>" + "<br>" + "<p>"+ commentList[cl].body + "</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>");
```